# How to write a command that produces such a matrix that takes n as an argument, where every node has probability 1/m

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, homework

[image: This is the complete question]

Please help in answering the questions above on mathematica. Which commands do I use to answer the question?

Comment: The problem description you show assumes a large amount of  a-priori knowledge on the part of the reader. Since you don't supply that knowledge or even a reference to it, it will be unlikely that anyone reading the question will have the background required to help you. Please provide enough information to ***completely*** describe the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 10;
Row[Table[
  RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, 1/m], 
   ImageSize -> 250], {m, 2, 4}]]
```

[image]

```
g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[250, 1/4]];

Histogram[Length /@ GatherBy[EdgeList@g, First]]
```

[image]